# How can I count and efficiently replace inner double-quotes in a string?

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a raw data file with approximately 2.6 million lines of data, and in each of these lines I have a string representing a URL. Unfortunately, some of these URLs have a rogue quotation mark in them:

"www.stackoverflow.com/quest"ions/ask"

My approach as of right now is to count the number of quotations in a line and if it's greater than two, simply use the first quotation and the last quotation in the line to determine where the string is supposed to start and end.

Is there a more efficient way to approach this?

EDIT:

The string that specifies the URL isn't the entire line, it's only a portion of the entire line. An entire line of data is as follows, and is delimited with spaces:

asc755.usask.ca - - [13/Jul/1995:17:27:51 -0600] "GET stackoverflow.com/pos"ts/41656163 HTTP/1.0" 200 2273

So I can't actually edit anything within the intended quotations, because the intended quotations are arbitrary.

Comment: the first and last quotations are in the string itself (es. str = '  "www.example.c"om"  ')

Answer (score 2):

I think it depends, how many urls are are broken. But you could skip counting and replace all double quotes. Afterwards add them back to the string.

```
s = '"www.stackoverflow.com/quest"ions/ask"'
x = '"%s"' % s.replace('"', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use a more powerful tool. Without seeing more examples of your inputs, I imagine you could use a simple regex to purge double-quotes that are embedded within strings. Grab everything between the string with this.

```
^"(.+)"$
```

Then replace the `"` with an empty string. Share more info about the data you're working with if it's more complicated than this.

Heres a link to a working capture. [Link](https://regex101.com/r/tqkGvj/2)